# Randomly doing a task over the next 5 hours inside a random for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

As you can see below, I have a simple for loop printing 4-8 times.

I am trying to make it so that it prints 4-8 times over randomly over 5 hours...

```
import random

for i in range(random.randrange(4,8+1)): 
    print i+1
    print "do other stuff here..."
```

For example it might do the following::

```
22:30: 1 do other stuff here...
22:41: 2 do other stuff here...
22:45: 3 do other stuff here...
23:50: 4 do other stuff here...
00:33: 5 do other stuff here...
01:23: 6 do other stuff here...
02:20: 7 do other stuff here...
03:10: 8 do other stuff here...
```

As it's random it could potentially do:

```
13:34: 1 do other stuff here...
13:41: 2 do other stuff here...
13:45: 3 do other stuff here...
13:50: 4 do other stuff here...
```

How can I get this working, I can't figure out how to get both loops running together..

### for William Denman

```
Sleeping for: 274 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 10 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 13 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 1 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 0 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 0 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 0 minutes
do other stuff here...
Sleeping for: 0 minutes
do other stuff here...
```

### For tobias_k

```
total = 30
timer_list = sorted(random.randint(1, total) for i in range(random.randint(4, 8)))
timer_old = 0
timer_previous = 0

print timer_list
for counter, timer in enumerate(timer_list):

    new_timer = timer_old - timer_previous
    timer_previous = timer_old
    sec = timedelta(seconds=int(new_timer))
    d = datetime(1,1,1) + sec
    if counter == 0:
        print "First is instantatious"
    else:
        if d.hour and d.minute:
            print "Sleeping for %d hour(s) %d minutes" % (d.hour, d.minute)
        elif not d.hour and d.minute:
            print "Sleeping for %d minutes and %d seconds" % (d.minute, d.second)
        else:
            print "Sleeping for %d seconds" % (d.second)
    print "done"
    time.sleep(timer - timer_old)
    timer_old = timer
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to make your program run for 5 hours and then stop?

Comment: Randomly choose n between 4 and 8, then choose n random numbers from 0 to 1 and stretch them to 5 hours.

Comment: @Hyflex Judging from your log, it seems you are experiencing the problem I expected. See Guntram's and my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another variant, based on Guntram's approach (and my own comment below the question):

```
import random, time
total = 3600 * 5
times = sorted(random.randint(1, total) for i in range(random.randint(4, 8)))
last = 0
for t in times:
    time.sleep(t - last)
    last = t
    print "Do something at %02d:%02d:%02d" % (t/3600, t/60%60, t%60)
```

This creates 4-8 points in time in the 5h interval and sorts them. Then it sleeps for the first interval, does something, sleeps for the difference of the first and the second, does something again, etc.

The (possible) advantage is that the intervals are independent of each other and should be distributed evenly over the entire 5h interval. In the other approaches, the intervals between the events are getting smaller and smaller, as they are a random amount of the time that's left.

Comment: Thank you, Tobias. That was exactly what i intended, just that i can't write python, i can only read it ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k I've been trying to edit that for the last 45 mins to make it so that the first is instantaneous then it says "sleeping for x" then it sleeps, then it does the next task... see my edit in top post :(

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. If you want the first execution to be instantaneous, just add another `print "Do something"` (or rather the actual task to be done) _before_ the loop.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes sir, Williams, your version and Guntram's ideas all work. I've mixed yours with some edits of my own. and made it quite a bit different.

Answer (score 4):

Get a random number between 4 and 8. Create an array with this many elements. Assign a random value between 0 and 18000 to each of the elements. Sort the array. Loop through the array elements. In each loop, sleep for the number of seconds in your array element minus the number of seconds you already slept in previous loops. Print "do other stuff here". Repeat until loop finishes.

Comment: Care to write a simple example as I don't quite get what you mean :S

Comment: To be honest, my python is quite rusty, and a perl or java or C program probably wouldn't help you. The idea is: you want your sleep times to sum up to 18000 (3600 sec/hr times 5 hrs). So you generate between four and eight values between 0 and 18000 - let's say 5 values, [17200, 8150, 9000, 2800, 15000] . When you sort them, you get [ 2800, 8150, 9000, 15000, 17200 ]. These are the points in time when you print out your message. Before printing the message, you sleep 2800 seconds, then (8150-2800)=5350 seconds, then 850 seconds, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import random
from time import gmtime, strftime

max_time_to_sleep = 18000
min_time_to_sleep = 120

for i in range(random.randrange(4,8+1)): 
    sleep_for = random.randrange(max_time_to_sleep)

while sleep_for < min_time_to_sleep:
   if max_time_to_sleep <= min_time_to_sleep:
       break

   sleep_for = random.randrange(max_time_to_sleep) 

if sleep_for == 0:
    sleep_for = min_time_to_sleep

time.sleep(sleep_for)

max_time_to_sleep -= sleep_for

if max_time_to_sleep < min_time_to_sleep:
    max_time_to_sleep = min_time_to_sleep

cur_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())

print "%s : do other stuff here..." % cur_time
```

Comment: He wants the sum of all sleep()s to be 18000 seconds, so he can't just sleep for the same time in each loop.

Comment: @WilliamDenman Hmm, interesting is it at all possible to "re-roll" if the next sleep time is under 120 seconds?

Comment: This will loop endlessly if your max_time_to_sleep happens to be less than 120 after the `max_time_to_sleep -= sleep_for`.  Ahh -- i just saw you fixed that :)

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I knew someone would catch that :D. It is unclear what OP would want in this case. Good at least to get rid of infinite loops. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that and changed it my end but didn't post. (I tried it on a small scale)

Comment: @WilliamDenman Ahh, just found a problem (see updated post for the issue) it can potentially run out of time and then sleep for 0 seconds (which is not intended.)

Comment: You can always just check for that and `break` or do something else accordingly. Perhaps a default time to 'wait'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random, time

# time left within the 5 hour window
timeLeft = 5 * 3600

for i in range(random.randint(4, 8)):
    # get a random sleep time from the remaining window and sleep for that time
    sleepTime = random.randrange(timeLeft)
    timeLeft -= sleepTime
    time.sleep(sleepTime)

    print('Execution #{}'.format(i))
    # do stuff
```

Comment: This will not distribute the events evenly. Expected value for first event is after 1/2 of total time, for second after 3/4, for third after 7/8, etc.

Comment: @tobias_k And that was not a requirement. The requirement is that there are between 4 and 8 runs and that they are randomly done within a 5 hour window. Look at the examples.

Comment: @poke is correct, that was not the requirement and that's what was confusing me. I read both this example and William's and facepalmed ^_^